# Gulp mismatch / Unsupported gulp version?

Tags: windows, gulp

I'm on Windows 10 and getting an `Unsupported gulp version` error when I gulp start my project.

gulp -v

```
CLI version 2.0.1
Local version 3.3.4
```

I cannot upgrade Gulp to 4 because that's too big a task, so how do I get up and running with 3.3.4?

I should note that this was working a few days ago but then I was working on another project which I did convert to Gulp 4 and I think something (gulp-cli?) got updated globally and now it's not happy.

I tried installing gulp-cli@1.4.0 but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I didn't need gulp-cli so I removed it (globally) and then installed regular gulp@3.3.4 globally and that did the trick.